# Knockout, How to add custom functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, knockout-3.0

I have this code:

```
interface KnockoutObservable<T> {
    reset() : void;
}

ko.observable.fn.reset = function () {
    return ko.pureComputed(function () {
        var target = this();

        var initialValue = target();
        target(null);
        target(initialValue);
    }, this);
}
```

In my calling code I have:

```
public selectedBoxOperator: KnockoutObservable<string>;
```

And I can now do:

```
this.selectedBoxOperator.reset();
```

The function pops-up with intellisence, but it is not executed. It skips the function...(I used the chrome debugger). Any idea how to get this to work? If this will works I can build more "extension" functions like this..

Comment: I'm not familiar with typescript, but wouldn't you also need to associate `KnockoutObservable<T>` with `ko.observable` in some fashion?

Comment: This is done by the interface. If I remove the interface the `reset` function does not pop-up by my intellisense..

Comment: But a suggestion is welcome, it doesn't work in this way for sure

Comment: Are you sure intellisense isn't just showing you the `reset` defined in the interface?  what happens if you remove `fn.reset` instead - does intellisense still remain?

Comment: You are right! If I remove `fn.reset` it is still there in intellisense. So it is just the interface which I call now.

Comment: So that's why it doesn't work. Any idea how to get it to work: I looked here: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/fn.html

Comment: Unfortunately not - I can talk about javascript and knockout, but not typescript.  Probably worth a google to see if there are other typescript knockout wrappers already that you can build from.

Comment: Tnkx anyway, one step further.. Maybe someone else has an idea?

Comment: Are you already using [something like this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/knockout/index.d.ts)? I note it already defines `KnockoutObservable<T>`, perhaps you need to extend that interface rather than redeclare it